# OpenCV + Python + multiprocessing won't work

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I think I found a bug in Python bindings for OpenCV, but since there is always a chance problem exists between the chair and the keyboard and not in the code, I thought to confirm here instead of submitting a ticket right away.

Here is a simple script for processing a bunch of images in parallel:

```
import cv2
import multiprocessing
import glob
import numpy

def job(path, output):

    image = cv2.imread(path)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    output.put(path)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    main_image = cv2.imread("./image.png")
    main_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    output = multiprocessing.Queue()

    processes = []

    for path in glob.glob("./data/*"):

        process = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=job,
            args=(path, output))

        process.start()
        processes.append(process)

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    # Collect all results
    results = [output.get() for process in processes]

    print 'Finished'
```

In this code `results = [output.get() for process in processes]` never finishes.
Now the really weird part is that if I comment out the `main_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` line, which should have no influence on parallel computations whatsoever, script does finish.

Both `./image.png` and paths at `./data/` lead to ordinary images, about ~20 of them in total.
I tried creating images in memory (`numpy.ones([100, 100, 3]).astype(numpy.float32)`) and that didn't produce the bug.

I have similar code written in C++ and it runs just fine.
My environment: OS X 10.10, OpenCV 3.0.0, Python 2.7

So, am I doing something silly, or does this indeed appear to be a bug in OpenCV that manifests in parallel computations?

---

Edit:
I also tried an implementation using multiprocessing.Pool.map() and the result is the same. Here's the code

```
import cv2
import multiprocessing
import glob
import numpy

def job(path):

    image = cv2.imread(path)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    return path

if __name__ == "__main__":

    image = cv2.imread("./image.png")
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    paths = glob.glob("./data/*")
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    result = pool.map(job, paths)

    print 'Finished'

    for value in result:
        print value
```

I was able to get correct results for such design with non-opencv tasks, so I strongly believe the problem is on opencv side. But please feel free to prove me wrong - I would love that since it would mean I don't have to resort to C++.

Comment: I have a similar problem for which I could not create a small failing example. Did you report this as a bug?

Comment: Yes. it's reported on https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/5150

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you `get` before you `join`?

According to [the python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#all-platforms):

> ### Joining processes that use queues
>
> Bear in mind that a process that has put items in a queue will wait
>   before terminating until all the buffered items are fed by the
>   “feeder” thread to the underlying pipe. (The child process can call
>   the cancel_join_thread() method of the queue to avoid this behaviour.)
>
> This means that whenever you use a queue you need to make sure that
>   all items which have been put on the queue will eventually be removed
>   before the process is joined. Otherwise you cannot be sure that
>   processes which have put items on the queue will terminate. Remember
>   also that non-daemonic processes will be joined automatically.
>
> An example which will deadlock is the following:
>
> ```
>  from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
>
>
>  def f(q):
>      q.put('X' * 1000000)
>
>
>  if __name__ == '__main__':
>      queue = Queue()
>      p = Process(target=f, args=(queue,))
>      p.start()
>      p.join()                    # this deadlocks
>      obj = queue.get()
> ```
>
> A fix here would be to swap the last two lines (or simply remove the p.join() line).

Comment: Hmm, looking a bit deeper on the web I see some people calling p.join() after queue.get(), but it leads to the same results for me :|

Comment: And btw - for some dummy problems without OpenCV I'm getting correct results going either way.

Comment: Also please have a look at my edit in which I used parallel map implementation.

Comment: Does the behavior change when you load in the images in the main thread? Loading all images in a list and provide loaded images i.s.o. paths.

Comment: I've seen that you opened a bug @ OpenCV (https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/5150), Could you update the status here when it is solved/confirmed?

Comment: no, code would crash all the same. I will try to remember to update the question when a bugfix comes out.